# Как в EditText выставить первый символ в верхний регистр?

Tags: android, android-edittext

В Андроид приложении есть EditText надо чтоб первый символ по умолчанию был в верхнем регистре, как?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте к Вашему `EditText` атрибут `inputType` со значением `"textCapSentences"`:

```
android:inputType="textCapSentences"
```

Answer (score 3):

Разобрался, в inputType= указываем следующее:

```
textCapWords - если надо чтоб каждый первый символ, каждого слова автоматически был в верхнем регистре.
textCapSentences -  каждый первый символ предложения.
textCapCharacters - все буквы сразу будут большими при наборе.
```